# PHP GD library, path to image in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, gd

I have controller in Surgery/PatientBundle/Constroller/RegistrationPatientBundleController and in Surgery/PatientBundle/Resources/public/images/test.jpg  I have a image. How is the path to this image ? I tried this code in my controller

```
public testAction(){

     header ( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
     $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("../Resources/public/images/test.jpg");
     imagejpeg($image);
```

But can't find file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$image => imagecreatefromjpeg(__DIR__.'/../Resources/public/images/test.jpg');
```

Comment: I had to add "/" but it works $image = imagecreatefromjpeg(__DIR__.'/../Resources/public/images/sara.jpg');